# Ownable() Declaration error

Tags: solidity

Having problems compiling this contract I found.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract MetaToken is Pausable{

string public name = 'MetaMetaMeta! Token';
uint8 public decimals = 8;
string public symbol = 'M3T';
string public version = '0.4.0';

uint256 public blockReward = 1 * (10**uint256(decimals));
uint32 public halvingInterval = 210000;
uint256 public blockNumber = 0; // how many blocks mined
uint256 public totalSupply = 0;
uint256 public target   = 0x0000ffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; // i.e. difficulty. miner needs to find nonce, so that (hash(nonce+random) < target)
uint256 public powLimit = 0x0000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
uint40 public lastMinedOn; // will be used to check how long did it take to mine
uint256 public randomness;

address public newContractAddress;

function MetaToken() Ownable() {
    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp);
    updateRandomness();
}

/// update randomness, will be used to find next Nonce
function updateRandomness() internal {
    randomness = uint256(sha3(sha3(uint256(block.blockhash(block.number-1)) + uint256(block.coinbase) + uint256(block.timestamp))));
}

/// returns `randomness` used in PoW calculations
function getRamdomness() view returns (uint256 currentRandomness) {
    return randomness;
}

/// pure, accepts randomness & nonce and returns hash as int (which should be compared to target)
function hash(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness) pure returns (uint256){
    return uint256(sha3(nonce+currentRandomness));
}

/// pure, accepts randomness, nonce & target and returns boolian whether work is good
function checkProofOfWork(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness, uint256 currentTarget) pure returns (bool workAccepted){
    return uint256(hash(nonce, currentRandomness)) < currentTarget;
}

// accepts Nonce and tells whether it is good to mine
function checkMine(uint256 nonce) view returns (bool success) {
    return checkProofOfWork(nonce, getRamdomness(), target);
}

/*
    accepts nonce aka "mining field", checks if it passess proof of work,
    rewards if it does
*/
function mine(uint256 nonce) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
    require(checkMine(nonce));

    Mine(msg.sender, blockReward, uint40(block.timestamp) - uint40(lastMinedOn)); // issuing event to those who listens for it

    balances[msg.sender] += blockReward; // giving reward
    blockNumber += 1;
    totalSupply += blockReward; // increasing total supply
    updateRandomness();

    // difficulty retarget:
    var mul = (block.timestamp - lastMinedOn);
    if (mul > (60*2.5*2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5*2;
    }
    if (mul < (60*2.5/2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5/2;
    }
    target *= mul;
    target /= (60*2.5);

    if (target > powLimit) { // difficulty not lower than that
        target = powLimit;
    }

    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp); // tracking time to check how much PoW took in the future
    if (blockNumber % halvingInterval == 0) { // time to halve reward?
        blockReward /= 2;
        RewardHalved();
    }

    return true;
}

function setNewContractAddress(address newAddress) onlyOwner {
    newContractAddress = newAddress;
}

event Mine(address indexed _miner, uint256 _reward, uint40 _seconds);
event RewardHalved();
```

}

The error -

```
browser/test.sol:31:26: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
    function MetaToken() Ownable() {
                         ^-----^
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ownable()` is a contract to manage the ownership. You need to import that contract too. You can find it [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the round brackets if Ownable is a modifier!

OR

Add Ownable modifier in Pausable contract and remove the round braces like this:

```
    function MetaToken() Ownable {
```

**EDITED**

Try this code instead:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol";

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner has the authority");
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}



contract MetaToken is Pausable, owned{

string public name = 'MetaMetaMeta! Token';
uint8 public decimals = 8;
string public symbol = 'M3T';
string public version = '0.4.0';

uint256 public blockReward = 1 * (10**uint256(decimals));
uint32 public halvingInterval = 210000;
uint256 public blockNumber = 0; // how many blocks mined
uint256 public totalSupply = 0;
uint256 public target   = 0x0000ffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; // i.e. difficulty. miner needs to find nonce, so that (hash(nonce+random) < target)
uint256 public powLimit = 0x0000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
uint40 public lastMinedOn; // will be used to check how long did it take to mine
uint256 public randomness;

address public newContractAddress;

mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

constructor () public {
    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp);
    updateRandomness();
}

/// update randomness, will be used to find next Nonce
function updateRandomness() internal {
    randomness = uint256(sha3(sha3(uint256(block.blockhash(block.number-1)) + uint256(block.coinbase) + uint256(block.timestamp))));
}

/// returns `randomness` used in PoW calculations
function getRamdomness() view returns (uint256 currentRandomness) {
    return randomness;
}

/// pure, accepts randomness & nonce and returns hash as int (which should be compared to target)
function hash(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness) pure returns (uint256){
    return uint256(sha3(nonce+currentRandomness));
}

/// pure, accepts randomness, nonce & target and returns boolian whether work is good
function checkProofOfWork(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness, uint256 currentTarget) pure returns (bool workAccepted){
    return uint256(hash(nonce, currentRandomness)) < currentTarget;
}

// accepts Nonce and tells whether it is good to mine
function checkMine(uint256 nonce) view returns (bool success) {
    return checkProofOfWork(nonce, getRamdomness(), target);
}

/*
    accepts nonce aka "mining field", checks if it passess proof of work,
    rewards if it does
*/
function mine(uint256 nonce) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
    require(checkMine(nonce));

    Mine(msg.sender, blockReward, uint40(block.timestamp) - uint40(lastMinedOn)); // issuing event to those who listens for it

    balances[msg.sender] += blockReward; // giving reward
    blockNumber += 1;
    totalSupply += blockReward; // increasing total supply
    updateRandomness();

    // difficulty retarget:
    uint256 mul = (block.timestamp - lastMinedOn);
    if (mul > (60*2.5*2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5*2;
    }
    if (mul < (60*2.5/2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5/2;
    }
    target *= mul;
    target /= (60*2.5);

    if (target > powLimit) { // difficulty not lower than that
        target = powLimit;
    }

    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp); // tracking time to check how much PoW took in the future
    if (blockNumber % halvingInterval == 0) { // time to halve reward?
        blockReward /= 2;
        RewardHalved();
    }

    return true;
}

function setNewContractAddress(address newAddress) onlyOwner {
    newContractAddress = newAddress;
}

event Mine(address indexed _miner, uint256 _reward, uint40 _seconds);
event RewardHalved();

}
```

Comment: I got another error now

      browser/XGD..sol:100:56: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
       function setNewContractAddress(address newAddress) onlyOwner() {
                                                       ^-------^

Comment: The import link you're using isn't working. I just checked. There is space in between too. Just make sure it's up to date. [https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol]

Comment: And function MetaToken is a constructor so remove the identifier. Constructor gets called automatically when the contract is deployed.

Comment: Thanks man, it seems like it should work, theres a new error

    browser/XGD.sol:16:17: ParserError: Expected identifier, got 'LParen'
    constructor () public {
                       ^

Comment: Maybe try changing from `constructor()` to `MetaToken()` i.e using class name instead of constructor keyword.